# block rendering some style sheets in _layout for specific pages

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

My project is ASP.NET MVC project. So in _layout there is are some CSS style sheet links that I do not want browser renders that CSS style sheets for the specific pages. How can I do that?

Comment: Then include it in the page, not the master layout (or have different layout files)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke but I have a lot of pages and I don't think it is correct to include that style sheet to all the pages not just layout because that stylesheet must not be rendered for just one page.

Comment: Then use 2 different layouts - one with and one without that css file

Comment: @Stephen Muecke but is it correct to create two identical layouts with and without that css file? Don't I repeat myself?